# Como utilizar uma tupla literal como propriedade de uma classe em C#

Tags: c#

Olá, estou trabalhando com C# e li sobre tuplas literais. Com isso, estou criando  a classe abaixo:

```
public class Foo 
{
    public (int bar, string bin)? barBin { get; set; }
}
```

Em teoria, pra eu conseguir utilizar essa classe e atribuir valores a essa tupla, eu iria fazê-la assim:

```
int testBar = 2;
string testBin = "hello world";

var foo = new Foo() 
{
    barBin = (bar: testBar, bin: testBin)
};
```

O problema é que quando utilizo essa declaração o VS me dá a mensagem `An expression tree may not contain a tuple literal`. também tentei passar uma tupla não declarada (`barBin = (testBar, testBin)`) mas não funciona.

Como faço para usar tuplas literais como propriedades em uma classe e trabalhar nelas?

Comment: Aqui funciona, está usando a versão certa? Mas já digo que fazer isso é abuso da tupla, não vi motivo pra usá-la aí. Na verdade eu acho que nem está compilando este código postado.

Comment: Aqui também está ok, de certeza que a versão que está a usar não permite o uso de tuplas literais.

Comment: O que exatamente você está querendo fazer, o erro é no código exposto na pergunta ou em um outro cenário que você não demonstrou aqui?

Comment: Estou usando o C#7, o uso da tupla é pra entender até onde consigo usar a mesma e suas vantagens e o erro que está sendo apresentado está diretamente no Main de um projeto de teste simples

Answer (score -2):

Só para lembrar. A classe Tuple foi introduzida no .NET Framework 4.0.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   var person = GetPerson();
}

static Tuple<int, string> GetPerson() 
{
   return Tuple.Create(1, "Fulano");
}
```

Espero ter ajudado.